# "rpm -qa --changelog package_name" not listing CVE numbers for one package, but works fine for others

Tags: rhel, security, rpm

**I'm trying to find out what vulnerabilities are already fixed for mysql* packages, but to my surprise the changelog is not listing any CVE numbers.**

When I run `rpm -qa --changelog package_name` it shows all the changelogs including the CVE numbers etc. as shown below:

```
[root@rhel7.4 ~]# rpm -qa --changelog kernel | grep -i cve | head -n10
- [mm] enlarge stack guard gap (Larry Woodman) [1452732 1452733] {CVE-2017-1000364}
- [fs] nfsd: stricter decoding of write-like NFSv2/v3 ops ("J. Bruce Fields") [1449282 1443204] {CVE-2017-7895}
- [fs] nfsd4: minor NFSv2/v3 write decoding cleanup ("J. Bruce Fields") [1449282 1443204] {CVE-2017-7895}
- [fs] nfsd: check for oversized NFSv2/v3 arguments ("J. Bruce Fields") [1447642 1442407] {CVE-2017-7645}
- [net] macsec: dynamically allocate space for sglist (Sabrina Dubroca) [1445546 1445545] {CVE-2017-7477}
- [net] macsec: avoid heap overflow in skb_to_sgvec (Sabrina Dubroca) [1445546 1445545] {CVE-2017-7477}
- [net] tcp: avoid infinite loop in tcp_splice_read() (Davide Caratti) [1430579 1430580] {CVE-2017-6214}
- [x86] kvm: x86: fix emulation of "MOV SS, null selector" (Radim Krcmar) [1414742 1414743] {CVE-2017-2583}
- [net] packet: fix overflow in check for tp_reserve (Hangbin Liu) [1441171 1441172] {CVE-2017-7308}
- [net] packet: fix overflow in check for tp_frame_nr (Hangbin Liu) [1441171 1441172] {CVE-2017-7308}
```

However, when I run check for mysql* package I do not have any CVE numbers listed:

```
[root@rhel7.4 ~]# rpm -qa --changelog mysql* | grep -i cve
[root@rhel7.4 ~]#
```

**Am I missing something, any configuration on the yum repositories etc. ?**

**From where rpm picks up changelog information, may be I need to rebuild that for mysql package?**

And yes without greping the contents I do see changelogs fine but without any CVE ofcourse:

```
[root@rhel7.4 ~]# rpm -qa --changelog mysql* | head -n10
* Wed Nov 08 2017 Bharathy Satish <bharathy.x.satish@oracle.com> - 5.7.21-1
- Add keyring_encrypted_file.so plugin

* Tue Oct 31 2017 Bjorn Munch <bjorn.munch@oracle.com> - 5.7.21-1
- Remove obsoleted mysqltest man pages

* Fri May 26 2017 Harin Vadodaria <harin.vadodaria@oracle.com> - 5.7.19-1
- Add keyring_aws.so plugin to commercial server subpackage

* Tue Sep 13 2016 Balasubramanian Kandasamy <balasubramanian.kandasamy@oracle.com> - 5.7.16-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changelog entry is free-form text. Some package maintainers put there CVE. Some bug id. Some describe every git change, some just put a brief summary there.

You cannot rely on the changelog. You have to find some other way.